# with large footnotes, and paperback format, reset the footnote counter at each page doesn't work perfectly

Tags: footnotes, counters, geometry

I want to reset the footnote counter on each page. This is very simple. Many packages exist. I prefer for my part to use tex :

```
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}
\makeatother
```

Unfortunately, all the ways to reset the footnote counter to zero at each page, does not work completely in my case.

I use, with geometry package, a paperback format. I use a lot of text in my footnote. The cause of this problem is probably due to the presence of large footnotes.

I enclose a minimal example: if you compile this example :

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,9pt]{book}

\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    right=1.2cm,
    left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm,
    bottom=1cm,
    paperwidth=110mm,
    paperheight=178mm
}


\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{footnote}{page}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  If you're looking for random\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} paragraphs, you've come to the right place. When a random word or a random sentence isn't quite enough, the next logical step is to find a random paragraph\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum}. We created\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} the Random Paragraph Generator with you in mind. The process is quite simple. Choose the number of random paragraphs you'd like to see and click the button. Your chosen number of paragraphs will instantly appear.

While it may not be obvious to everyone, there are a number of reasons creating random paragraphs can be useful. A few examples of how some people use this generator are listed in the following paragraphs.
Creative Writing\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum}

Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} use creativity to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it. A second option is to use the random paragraph somewhere in a short story they create. The third option is to have the random paragraph be the ending paragraph in a short story. No matter which of these challenges is undertaken, the writer is forced to use creativity to incorporate the paragraph into their writing.
Tackle Writers' Block

A random paragraph can also be an\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} excellent way for a writer to tackle writers' block. Writing block can often happen due to being stuck with a current project that the writer is trying to complete. By inserting a completely random paragraph from which to begin, it can take down some of the issues that may have been causing the writers' block in the first place.
Beginning Writing Routine

Another productive way to use this tool to begin a daily writing routine. One way is to generate a random paragraph with the intention to try to rewrite it while still keeping the original meaning. The purpose here is to just get the writing started\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} so that when the writer goes onto their day's writing projects, words are already flowing from their fingers.
Writing Challenge
\end{document}
```

you will see that, on page 2, the first footnote, which should be numbered 1, is numbered 5. Similarly on page 3, with the first footnote being wrongly numbered 2.

I also attach pictures, so that you can see [image]

I can't get around this problem.

any ideas? thanks a lot!

Comment: Well there is a reason why there are packages. Better use e.g. footmisc with the perpage option.

Comment: Yes i tried with \usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}. But the result is the same.

Comment: Sorry can't test now but did you compile twice? Side remark: don't use utf8x, it will break e.g. with hyperref.

Comment: I tried now. Numbering is fine after the second compilation if I replace your reset code by the  footmisc package.

Comment: Indeed. . I just tried too. But in my concrete application, it causes errors. I have to look at it and I answer you. thank you ;)

Comment: If you were wondering why, paragraphs and footnotes are formatted before being added to the output and may wind up on the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To follow up on @UlrikeFischer's suggestions: Do load the [footmisc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc) package with the `perpage` package, i.e., replace your code with

```
\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}
```

While you're at it, it's probably a good idea to employ the `splitrule` option as well:

```
\usepackage[perpage,splitrule]{footmisc}
```

Just be sure to recompile the document *at least twice*.

By the way, no need or cause to load the `inputenc` package with the `utf8x` option.

A separate comment: the `book` document class does not recognize, and simply ignores, the option `9pt`. If it's important to you to use a basic font size of 9pt, be sure to run

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,9pt]{extbook}
```

---

The following screenshot shows the first few lines of the footnote material on page 2 of the test document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[hidelinks,9pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
    paperwidth=110mm, paperheight=178mm,
    right=1.2cm, left=1.8cm,
    top=1.8cm, bottom=1cm
}
\usepackage[perpage,splitrule]{footmisc}


\begin{document}

If you're looking for random\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} paragraphs, you've come to the right place. When a random word or a random sentence isn't quite enough, the next logical step is to find a random paragraph\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum}. We created\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} the Random Paragraph Generator with you in mind. The process is quite simple. Choose the number of random paragraphs you'd like to see and click the button. Your chosen number of paragraphs will instantly appear.

While it may not be obvious to everyone, there are a number of reasons creating random paragraphs can be useful. A few examples of how some people use this generator are listed in the following paragraphs.
Creative Writing\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum}

Generating random paragraphs can be an excellent way for writers to get their creative flow going at the beginning of the day. The writer has no idea what topic the random paragraph will be about when it appears. This forces the writer to use creativity to complete one of three common writing challenges. The writer can use the paragraph as the first one of a short story and build upon it.\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} A second option is to use the random paragraph somewhere in a short story they create. The third option is to have the random paragraph be the ending paragraph in a short story. No matter which of these challenges is undertaken, the writer is forced to use creativity to incorporate the paragraph into their writing.
Tackle Writers' Block

A random paragraph can also be an\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} excellent way for a writer to tackle writers' block. Writing block can often happen due to being stuck with a current project that the writer is trying to complete. By inserting a completely random paragraph from which to begin, it can take down some of the issues that may have been causing the writers' block in the first place.
Beginning Writing Routine

Another productive way to use this tool to begin a daily writing routine. One way is to generate a random paragraph with the intention to try to rewrite it while still keeping the original meaning. The purpose here is to just get the writing started\footnote{Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum} so that when the writer goes onto their day's writing projects, words are already flowing from their fingers.
Writing Challenge

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `\usepackage[perpage]{footmisc}`, it works.

I don't know why it doesn't work the last few days.

Thank you to all!